# How do I select from multiple tables in one query with Django?

Tags: python, django, join, django-queryset

I have two tables, one "Company" and one "Employee":

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    company = models.ForeignField(Company)
```

And I want to list every Employee in a table, with the Company next to it. Which is simple enough by calling `employees = Employee.objects.all()` and in the template loop trough it and calling `{{employee.company.name}}`.

The problem with this solutions is that it will be created a new query for each item in the loop. So for each Employee there will be one query to Company looking something like this:

```
SELECT `company`.`id`, `company`.`name`
FROM `company`
WHERE `company`.`id` = 1 # This will of course be the employee.company_id
```

Instead I wish to make this join initially in the same query getting the Employees. Something like this:

```
SELECT `employee`.`name` AS `name`,
       `company`.`name` AS `company_name`
FROM `employee` INNER JOIN `company` ON `employee`.`company_id` = `company`.`id`
```

Is this possible with the Django QuerySet? If not, is there a way I can work around to solve this(without raw sql)? Or should this behavior be ignored, cached and considered "optimized"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using  [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)  will pre-populate the appropriate attributes:

```
Employee.objects.select_related()
```

Comment: I have read the documentation up and down, but managed to totally miss this part. Well thanks alot! That was embarrassing.

Comment: Most do the first time. Django docs should look into this aspect.

Answer (score 22):

It is an old question, let me provide a new answer.

Actually, you can do this:

```
employees = Employee.objects.all().values('id','name','company__name')
```

then, Django will automatically lookup Company class and find the company name for you.

on the template page, use {{employees.company__name}} then it will display the company name correctly.

Comment: This was an old question, and i'm glad you answered it. I've been running in circles trying to create a query from a base table that has one-to-many relationships with two tables. `select_related()` wasn't helping me unless I was only interested in related data from one table; this however, was easy to adapt to my situation and it works great!

Comment: This has to be one of the most useful posts that I have found. One thing, did you mean `{{employees.company__name}} with an 's'

Comment: @matt - I assume he's implying a loop with `employee` on employees... I could be wrong though. I'm fairly new to Django.

Comment: @hepcat72 - Yes, you have to do a loop on the employees.

Answer (score 10):

I guess what you're looking for is the select_related method of your queryset. 
See [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

> select_related()
>
> Returns a QuerySet that will
>   automatically "follow" foreign-key
>   relationships, selecting that
>   additional related-object data when it
>   executes its query. This is a
>   performance booster which results in
>   (sometimes much) larger queries but
>   means later use of foreign-key
>   relationships won't require database
>   queries

Answer (score 2):

## With raw queries

```
    qry1 = "SELECT c.car_name, p.p_amount FROM pay p, cars c where p.user_id=%s;"

    cars = Cars.objects.raw(qry1, [user_id])
```