# Accessing objects from another model using foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-models

In my django project I have a model which stores location of a user with the `user_id` being a foreign key to the django `User` model. Here is the model

```
class Points(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
```

Now I want to execute a query like this:

```
Points.objects.filter(user_id=id).values_list('user_id','lat','lon')
```

but I also want the `username` field from django's `User` model in this list. Is there anyway I can do this without having to execute another query like `User.objects.get(id=id).value_list('username')` and then joining the two lists. I went through [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) but I am not sure if I can use them here.

Comment: Using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4). Check out this 2 questions, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425603/how-do-i-select-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query-with-django, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092268/how-do-you-join-two-tables-on-a-foreign-key-field-using-django-orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the double underscore notation to get related fields in a single call. Try this instead:

```
Points.objects.filter(user_id=id)
              .values_list('user_id', 'lat', 'lon', 'user_id__username')
```

(Though you should rename `user_id` to `user`. Django appends `_id` to your foreign key fields, which means that you now have two attributes: `user_id`, which will evaluate to the `User` object, and `user_id_id`, which will evaluate to the numerical id.)

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I needed. I didn't know that django appended `_id` by itself. I'll rename it.