# Django: Select data from two tables with foreigin key to third table

Tags: django, postgresql, select, foreign-keys

I have following models:

```
class Dictionary(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(unique=True)

class ProcessedText(models.Model):
    text_id = models.ForeiginKey('Text')
    word_id = models.ForeignKey('Dictionary')

class UserDictionary(models.Model):
    word_id = models.ForeignKey('Dictionary')
    user_id = models.ForeignKye('User')
```

I want to make query using django ORM same with next sql

```
SELECT * FROM ProcessedText, UserDictionary WHERE 
    ProcessedText.text_id = text_id 
AND ProcessedText.word_id = UserDictionary.word_id
AND UserDictionary.user_id = user_id
```

How to do it in one query without using cycles?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

[How do I select from multiple tables in one query with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425603/how-do-i-select-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query-with-django)

And also you may have to restructure your models to enable [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4)  concept of django.