# Return results from more than one database table in Django

Tags: sql, django

Suppose I have 3 hypothetical models;

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state = models.ForeignField(State)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state = models.ForeignField(State)
```

I want to be able to return results in a Django app, where the results, if using SQL directly, would be based on a query such as this:

```
SELECT a.name as 'personName',b.name as 'companyName', b.state as 'State'
FROM Person a, Company b
WHERE a.state=b.state
```

I have tried using the `select_related()` method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425603/how-do-i-select-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query-with-django?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't think this is quite what I am after, since I am trying to join two tables that have a common foreign-key, but have no key-relationships amongst themselves.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `Person` can have multiple `Company`s in the same state. It is not a good idea to do the `JOIN` at the database level. That would mean that the database will (likely) return the same `Company` multiple times, making the output quite large.

We can prefetch the related companies, with:

```
qs = Person.objects.select_related('state').prefetch_related('state__company')
```

Then we can query the `Company`s in the same state with:

```
for person in qs:
    print(person.state.company_set.all())
```

You can use a [**`Prefetch`**-object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) to prefetch the list of related companies in an attribute of the `Person`, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

qs = Person.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('state__company', Company.objects.all(), to_attr='same_state_companies')
)
```

Then you can print the companies with:

```
for person in qs:
    print(person.same_state_companies)
```