# How to get data from two table through one query Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

** I just need one more table join in my query **
I want to get sales of logged-in users with order detail and shipping address.
I am getting sales of current user through this query but i also want get shipping address.

```
orderitems = OrderItem.objects.filter(
    product__user=request.user, order__complete=1).order_by('-date_orderd')
```

Now i want to get also address, city and state from the Shippingaddress model.
I attached the models below.

this is my current result.
[image: as you can see in the image address city and state is missing]

My models:
Order Model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date_orderd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    # product = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Order items Model:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_orderd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

Shipping Address Model:

```
class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_orderd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

Answer (score 1):

What  you are looking for is "Select from multiple tables in one query with Django". You can take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425603/how-do-i-select-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query-with-django/48341567).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my scenario is little bit difference. Shipping address model having foreign key of order id. There is no directly relationship between them. Orderitems and shipping address model. Please check my models. How i can i access the both tables values in one query?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add another query like the one below

```
shp_address = ShippingAddress.objects.filter(product__user=request.user)
```

and if needed send to the client side as part of context, see below

```
context = {
        'orderitems':  orderitems,
        'shp_address': shp_address
}
```

Comment: I also tried like this `address = ShippingAddress.objects.filter(
        order__in=Subquery(orderitems.values('order'))).order_by('-date_orderd')  detail = zip(order, orderitems, address)`. but on template it is getting desired values from tables but its not getting complete rows.

Comment: (1) `ShippingAddress` should be related to `User` rather than `Order`.  (2)  Why for each `OrderItem` you need to store user id. Last, are trying to get shipping address(s) of a specific user?

Comment: actually I want to get sales of sellers. I have a multivendor system there are different users (sellers and buyers). actually `user_id` in `OrderItem` are those who have purchased item. using this query `orderitems = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        product__user=request.user, order__complete=1).order_by('-date_orderd')` i am getting complete sales but I also want to get `address`,`state`,'zip` from shipping address. I tried in different ways but not getting right results. please help me . thanks

Comment: may be you edit your question above and provide more details. Second, since there is no relationship between `OrderItem` and `ShippingAddress `, if a user has more than 1 shipping address you will not be able to link it with correct OrderItems.

Comment: actually I am facing the same problem. if there are more than 1 `orderitems` related with 1 `ShippingAddress` than only 1 `orderitem` is showing. how can I solve this problem?