# How to obtain data from two tables and that two table join using Foreign-key in the Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am quite new to Django. I'm writing and app using Vue3 in the frontend and Django5 in the backend. I've implemented login already, but I want the user returning to contain the role, that happens to be in another table, and I just get the id.

My Django models:

```py
class Role(models.Model):
    id_role = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(models.Model):
    id_user = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    role_id = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    locale = models.TextField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Serializers:

```py
class RoleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = (
            'id_role', 'name', 'permissions'
        )

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id_user', 'email', 'password', 'role_id', 'locale'
        )
```

This is my viewset, where I have the login method, and I want it to return the role name instead of the role_id:

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def login(self, request, pk=None):
        user = serializers.serialize('json', self.queryset.filter(email=request.data["email"], password=request.data["password"]))
        if (user and user != "[]"):
            return Response(user)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "The user does not exist"},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I've already looked at SO questions ([How to make an Inner Join in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128714/how-to-make-an-inner-join-in-django)) and tried using this code:

```py
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def login(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = User.objects.select_related('roles')
        user = serializers.serialize('json', queryset.filter(email=request.data["email"], password=request.data["password"]))
        if (user and user != "[]"):
            return Response(user)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "The user does not exist"},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but I just get this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1367, in get_related_selections
     raise FieldError(
     django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'roles'. Choices are: role_id
```

When I try using role_id I just get the same response that in the beginning. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

---

EDIT: I just tried this answer also (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48341567/4639580), but I got:

```
FieldError at /api/users/login/
Cannot resolve keyword 'role' into field. Choices are: email, id_user, locale, password, person, role_id, role_id_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/users/login/
Django Version: 5.0.2
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'role' into field. Choices are: email, id_user, locale, password, person, role_id, role_id_id
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py, line 1772, in names_to_path
```

Comment: You can modify your `UserSerializer` set `role_id` to this `role_id = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='role_id.name')
` it will return name instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select_related method to perform an inner join between the tables.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.select_related('role_id')

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def login(self, request, pk=None):
        email = request.data["email"]
        password = request.data["password"]

        user = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, email=email, password=password)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

In the above code, select_related('role_id') is used to fetch the related Role object for each User object in the queryset. This eliminates the need for an additional database query when accessing the role_id field.

Note that you need to use the field name role_id instead of roles because the foreign key field in the User model is defined as role_id.

then, the user object is serialized using the serializer defined for the User model, and the serialized data is returned in the response.

Comment: Was this written by a chatbot (*ChatGPT*, *Google Gemini*, etc.)?

Comment: NO, this wasn't written by a chatbot.

Comment: Hi, I get that I defined role_id as FK. I tried your approach and I get the same as the beginning. no changes. I still get role_id and no role name :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with my same problem, and not finding the solution in select_related. Please make sure that you have the necessary nested serializers. In my case, my error was that I missed the nested serializer for the role model.

So this is what I did:

My models:

```
class RoleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = (
            'id_role', 'name', 'permissions'
        )

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    role_id = RoleSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id_user', 'email', 'password', 'role_id', 'locale'
        )
```

My view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.select_related('role_id').all()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def login(self, request, pk=None):
        email=request.data["email"]
        password=request.data["password"]

        user = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, email=email, password=password)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And now it's working. Thanks to you all.